# Debugging shared library residing in other directory in Eclipse/mingw

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gdb, mingw

I'm working in Eclipse on Windows, using mingw for the compiling environment.  My project has two parts:  a library and an executable, both in separate directories.

I want to debug the shared library that I've created, but when I tell Eclipse to load the program for debugging, it just hangs forever.  However, if I manually place the .dll file into the directory with the program, debugging proceeds normally.

I can certainly compile the static version of the library, which I'm doing now so as to be able to complete the project on time, but it offends my sensibilities that I can't get it to work right dynamically.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the path to your DLL file to the environement variable "PATH"?
To add to environment variable:
Right click "My Computer" -> Property -> Advanced -> environment variable

Comment: So, that worked.  I suppose I should have tried that before asking here.  But I was under the assumption that I could set this in Eclipse, and avoid having to muck up my general environment.  I went into the Debug configurations page and added the path to the DLL to the Environment Path variable, but although it works for running and finding the DLL, it seems to not affect the debug settings.  Any ideas why?